# Android Calendar View for Date Picker

Tags: android, calendar, android-datepicker

I'm writing my first app, and I have a question about `DatePicker`.

My app requires the user to input a date. The most user-friendly way would be to popup a calendar-like widget that displays the current month like a calendar grid - something like this:

[image]

I want to use that in place of the `DatePicker` interface - which has Month, Day, and Year fields, each with an up and down button to increment/decrement.

Is this type of functionality built into any Android widget or view, or would I have to design my own custom component to do this? I figured this would already exist, seeing how much this type of UI is used so frequently in non-mobile apps and web pages.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please update the selected answer to this question?  People may be mislead if they don't look at all the answers.  As stated by other people's responses, there is a CalendarView in API level 11+.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is this type of functionality built into any android widget or view, or would I have to design my own custom > component to do this?

There is no component for that in the Android SDK, sorry. The widget you illustrate is too small for a touchscreen. You can implement something larger (see the Calendar app), but you are largely on your own for that.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the Calendar App that you have mentioned in your answer..

Answer (score 19):

Now, in 2014, even the native [`DatePicker` (link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) contains small Holo looking [`CalendarView` (link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) to pick a day in month.

You can choose, if both spinners and `CalendarView` or just one of them is displayed by setting:

- `android:calendarViewShown`
- `android:spinnersShown`

I'm not sure if it's just API level 16+ or if it was even in Ice Cream Sandwich, but it's there. This is how it looks by default:

[image]

---

Moreover, on API level 21 and higher there is a new Material themed `DatePicker` that looks like following:

[image]

This is default on API 21+ and there are no spinners anymore, but you can switch back to the Holo one by setting

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```

in your XML.

Comment: Tried it out for fun on ICS, looks like holo

Answer (score 12):

Since the API 11 there natively: [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)

[image]

This View is in [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) since API 7.

Answer (score 7):

what i found so far:

- http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view
- http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/CalendarPickerAPI

Comment: how do resize these calendars properly?

Answer (score 4):

I have recently written exactly this as a modular app.  Here is some [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/#svn/trunk/calendarpicker/CalendarPickerDemo), [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/CalendarPickerAPI) with [screenshots](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/CalendarPickerAPI#Screenshots), and [.apk download](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/downloads/list).

Comment: could you tell me how to implement the calendar Plugin ? there is no info on how to install it

Answer (score 4):

Found a good implemetation in http://caughtinthemobileweb.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/how-to-implement-calendarview-in-android/

---

Also Since API level 11 (Android 3.0) there has been the native implementation of the CalendarView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Comment: +1 for mentioning the native date picker. There's also the DatePickerDialog: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html

Comment: and here is great rewrite without grid view: https://github.com/AtRow/CalendarView

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this component:
https://github.com/truefedex/android-date-picker
[image]

If you want to use it like popup write on your onclick:

```
if (calendarPopup == null) {
  calendarPopup = new PopupWindow(getContext());
  CalendarPickerView calendarView = new CalendarPickerView(getContext());
  CalendarNumbersView calendar = (CalendarNumbersView) calendarView.findViewById(com.phlox.datepick.R.id.calendar);
  calendar.setShowDayNames(false);
  calendarView.setListener(onDateSelectionListener);
  calendarPopup.setContentView(calendarView);
  calendarPopup.setWindowLayoutMode(
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(llCalendar.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  calendarPopup.setHeight(1);
  calendarPopup.setWidth(llCalendar.getWidth());
  calendarPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
}
calendarPopup.showAsDropDown(llCalendar);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this lib for date selection

https://github.com/square/android-times-square/