# Calendar UI in android

Tags: android, calendar

I am working on application in which i want to show a calendar in my UI. Can anyone please help me , how to do this. Any help will be appreciated ...
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check this android widget: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Check this also for example:

[Android Calendar View for Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712710/android-calendar-view-for-date-picker)

Try this and if you need any help, please come back again!

Hope this helps for now!