# Android Calendar Plugin

Tags: android, calendar

I am looking to implement a Calendar Plugin like in the screenshot below

[image]

Is there Any Plugin or some kind of code available opensource that we can use ?

Comment: also since api 11 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one: [CalendarPickerAPI](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/CalendarPickerAPI)

Just googled for "android calendar picker" and found it on a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712710/android-calendar-view-for-date-picker).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a project developed by developers for calender view in android....

http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/

Comment: change type of your answers, have to check how to wrote nice answers, otherwise could be http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122526/serially-flagging-for-a-single-user-on-so possible again