# Material Design Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on a Spinner

Tags: android, datepicker

I am looking to follow the material design guidelines on having a spinner like this:
[image]

And when clicked it should pupup a DatePickerDialog like this:

[image]

And finally when date chosen, get the chosen date inside the spinner like this:
[image]

I need help with how do I declare such a spinner in xml?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712710/android-calendar-view-for-date-picker refer to @anoniim answer

Comment: Thank you @karansky for the link, but that`s not what I need, I need the way its presented in the question.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Your title is quite misleading, from the title, I thought you wanted a calender pop up. After carefully reading your description, you want a spinner that looks like the pic? You have already achieved the calender pop up? If that's the case, I would recommend you to use custom adapter for the spinner to achieve the result. There might be a theme out there that fits what you want but I don't know which theme should that be

Answer (score 1):

add `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"` (or similar) to the 'date' text view.